# How do I open a link to a website on a new window in a browser and block the current website until the user finish or close the new one?

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I'm working with Mercado Pago API, but the thing is that I want when the user clicks the pay button, I want to open a new window in the browser (chrome, firefox, etc.) in the middle of the screen where is going to fill his credit card number and all that stuff meanwhile i want that the background site (I mean the main site where the user clicked on pay) to be blocked, like with darker colors, and not be able to do anything in that site until the user close the new window or he finish with the payment. I've been looking on the internet but I haven't found anything related to the blocked site. Maybe you could help me or have any idea to make that. thanks in advance.

Comment: use a modal for this, not a new browser window.

Comment: You should probably learn ajax

Answer (score 0):

I can't make comments, so sorry in advance for this being an "answer". But are you not able to store information about what the user has selected and then use the current page to process the payment, then bring back or send off what they wanted? perhaps using AJAX to run a PHP page that stores something. Just a suggestion but not entirely an answer, because AFAIK you can't "block" tabs as that could be very dangerous and could be used for the wrong reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The task you want to do requires both back-end programming (php/server-side) and a bit of front-end jquery(js) + ajax.

For front-end something like this could be your start.
[Bootstrap Static Modal Example](https://jsbin.com/nusuzoxobi/edit?html,js,output).

And you would need to put your form there, submit it via ajax, and on success close the modal.

I hope this could help you a bit, and get you started in the right direction.

*Note: This is not particularly safe. (It's not hard to hide the modal and fiddle around the page in the background.*